# unable to delete excel file in java code getting error as The process canot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting error while deleting excel file using java code
below is exception

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Finance Reports\ArvindBTA.xlsx (The
>   process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process)

The code I am using is

```
final File file=new File("E:\\book1.xlsx");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c taskkill /f /im excel.exe");

new Thread(new Runnable() 
{

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        try {
               Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);// you need to wait 1-2 sec to close file before delete
               file.delete();   

           } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the file you are trying to delete is exist or not,

Please refer syntax for same,

```
file.exists()
```

Using this check you can sure that file is exist.

So your code if delete should be something like,

```
if(file.exists())
  file.delete();
```

One more thing you need to check if there is file on the path you specified. E:\book1.xlsx

Comment: I have tried using file.exist()
but it does not work and file is present in same path

Comment: Is there any another way to delete file using java